# Communicating between Angular components and non-Angular components: Returning data from an observable coming from a callback

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an application that requires that I use non-Angular JavaScript for certain things. To trigger an action in the Angular component, I'm passing a down a callback to the non-Angular component. When the callback is triggered, an observable runs on the Angular component (doing an http call). This works but the only piece of the puzzle I'm having trouble with is getting the data returned from this observable passed back down to the non-Angular component somehow. My actual application is fairly complex so I've created a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yvtzco) for a much more simplified version to make it easier to see what I'm doing.

This is tricky for me as the `GET` call in `doStuff` is async, so I can't just return the results. I'd have some ideas on how to work around this in a pure Angular app... but I'm not sure how to accomplish this when sharing data between an Angular component and a Non-Angular one.

app.component.ts:

```
 export class AppComponent  {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  doStuff() {
    let randomNum = this.getRandomInt(2); // Simulate different http responses

    this.http.get<any>(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${randomNum}`).subscribe(x => {
      if (x === 1) {
        // Here is where I want to share data with the non-Angular component
        console.log(x.id);
      } else {
        // Here is where I want to share data with the non-Angular component
        console.log(x.id);
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
   var x = new NonAngularComponent(this.doStuff.bind(this));
  }

  private getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max)) + 1;
  }
}
```

NonAngularComponent.ts:

```
export class NonAngularComponent {
  constructor(private onSave: () => void) {
    this.init()
  }

  init() {
    const newElement = document.createElement('button');
    newElement.innerHTML = 'Click';

    newElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.onSave(); // Works, but now I need to do something with the results of doStuff()
    });

    document.getElementById('foo').append(newElement);
  }
}
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to return `Observable` from your `doStuff()` method and use `tap` operator if you want to have some side effect in Angular component:

```
doStuff() {
  let randomNum = this.getRandomInt(2);

  return this.http.get<any>(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${randomNum}`).pipe(tap(x => {
    if (x === 1) {
      // Here is where I want to share data with the non-Angular component
      console.log(x.id);
    } else {
      // Here is where I want to share data with the non-Angular component
      console.log(x.id);
    }
  }));
}
```

**non-angular.component.ts**

```
newElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
  this.onSave().subscribe(res => {
    // do whatever you want
  });
});
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c7ysnb?file=src%2Fapp%2FNonAngularComponent.ts)**

Comment: Ah! I did not think of subscribing in the non-Angular component using RxJS. This is incredibly helpful--thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the easiest solution would be to simply have an instance of your NonAngularComponent inside the AppComponent

```
this.nonAngularComponent = new NonAngularComponent(this.doStuff.bind(this));
```

And in the callback simply call the method you want from the NonAngularComponent like so:

```
doStuff() {
    let randomNum = this.getRandomInt(2);
    this.http
      .get<any>(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${randomNum}`)
      .subscribe(x => {
        if (x === 1) {
          // Here is where I want to share data with the non-Angular component
          // console.log(x.id);
          this.nonAngularComponent.doSomething(x);
        } else {
          // Here is where I want to share data with the non-Angular component
          // console.log(x.id);
          this.nonAngularComponent.doSomething(x);
        }
      });
  }
```

`doSomething` method:

```
  public doSomething(result) {
    console.log("Non-Angular component received result", result);
  }
```

And console output:

[image]

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tddc7q?file=src%2Fapp%2FNonAngularComponent.ts